# Swift - Instance member cannot be used on type ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting the following error on my circleLayer.strokeEnd line: "Instance member 'sales' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'." Does anyone know why I can't divide an Int by another Int and use it here? (Before this, I had 1.0 in place of "(sales/salesGoal)" and it worked great). This is a very simplified version of the code I'm using.

```
var sales = 0
var salesGoal = 2

  class salesCircleView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

       circleLayer.strokeEnd = (sales/salesGoal)

    }
  }
```

Any help figuring out the correct syntax would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Your error is not due to the division. Is this inside of a class called ViewController? that is probably where your problems lie.

Comment: You should consider posting the code for you View Controller, specifically those parts that show the context for your declaration of `sales` and `salesGoal` as well as where in the View Controller you try to access them. Also, note that if these variables are declared in the class View Controller they cannot be accessed in a different class (well not without a little work).

Answer (score 0):

So I did find that all of my code (including my variables) was inside a class called "View Controller" at the top. I moved the sales and salesGoal variables outside that class, now under the 'Import UIKit" and it worked like a charm.